# How can I get content of my text-box in html as separate words when its entered separated by a comma?

Tags: javascript, html, textbox

For example suppose i have a text box to write names of students who wants to join the class trip
in the text box we have to enter name one after the other separated by a '*comma*' (,).

while taking the value by **document.getElementById()** function, how can i get the names individually??

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put that into a variable and then put it into an array;

```js
var names;
var namesArray = [];
var inputBox = document.getElementById("names")
var getNames = document.getElementById("getNames");

getNames.onclick = function() {
  names = inputBox.value;

  namesArray = names.split(', ');

  //console.log(namesArray);

  /* DO SOMETHING WITH ARRAY OF NAMES */

  for (var i = 0; i < namesArray.length; i++) {
    console.log(namesArray[i]);
  }
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="names" value="Aba, Sam, Harry, Ronald">
<button id="getNames">GET NAMES</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @Icewine :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the value as a string, you can can just use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to convert the values to an array, given a separator in the form of a string or a regex:

```js
var $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

$("#submit").onclick = function() {
  var tokens = $("#text").value.split(/[, ]+/);
  console.log(tokens);
};
```

```css
* { font-size: 16pt; }
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="text">student1, student2</textarea>
</div>
<button id="submit">Parse!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks @4castle :)